# ServiceNow spUtil

Tags: angularjs, widget, servicenow

I'm trying to make a slight improvement to an existing widget that our team created, but can't seem to get it to work correctly.  We have a widget that does a RowCount of tasks and groups them by state.  I want the RowCount to auto update once a task is complete without having the user press the refresh button.  I've read some documentation on $rootscope, $broadcast, and $on, but can't seem to get it to work.

Below is snippet of our HTML:

```
<table class="table table-sm table-responsive">  
      <tbody>  
        <tr class="h3">  
          <td colspan=2>Complete</td>  
        </tr>  
        <tr class="h2 bg-success" ng-repeat="x in data.values track by $index">  
          <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span></td>  
          <td>{{x.completedCount}}</td>  
        </tr>  
      </tbody>  
    </table>
```

A snippet of our Server Script:

```
var values = [];  
var _completedCount;  

var gsCompleted = new GlideRecordSecure('sn_hr_core_task');  
//CLOSED COMPLETE, CLOSED INCOMPLETE,   
gsCompleted.addQuery('state', 'IN', '3,4,7');  
gsCompleted.addQuery('assigned_to', gs.getUserID());  
gsCompleted.addQuery("parent.state", 'NOT IN', '1,800,900');  
gsCompleted.query();  

if(gsCompleted){  
_completedCount = gsCompleted.getRowCount();  
}  
else{  
_completedCount = 0;  
}  

values.push(  
{  
completedCount: _completedCount  
});  
data.values = values;
```

How do I get this widget to auto update the Completed row count without refreshing the page?  I've been playing around with spUtil recordWatch, but cannot get it to work correctly:

```
function($scope, $sce, spUtil) {
        var c = this;
c.data.loading = true;

    //After page initially loads re-call server script to load data
    c.server.get({
        action: 'retrieve_data'
    }).then(function(response) {
        c.data.loading = false;

        console.log('Response');
        console.log(response);

        c.data.values = response.data.values;

        spUtil.recordWatch($scope, 'sn_hr_core_task', "", function(name,data) {
            spUtil.update($scope);
        })  

        });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the widget **Simple List**, it has an example of one that may help a bit.

You should be able to change your `recordWatch` to this

```
var filter = "stateIN3,4,7^parent.stateNOT IN1,800,900^assigned_to=" + window.NOW.user_id;
spUtil.recordWatch($scope, 'sn_hr_core_task', filter);
```

You generally won't need a callback function unless there is some specific action you're triggering.